# Using mat-menu as a context menu: getting the positioning right

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to build a context menu using mat-menu, and I feel like I'm pretty close.  I want the menu to pop-up where the user right-clicks.  The problem is that it's popping up where the user last right-clicked, not where they currently right-clicked.  How do I fix this?

HTML:

```
<span #contextMenuTrigger [matMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenu" class="context-menu-trigger" [style.left.px]="menuLeft" [style.top.px]="menuTop"></span>
<div (contextmenu)="openContextMenu($event)> stuff that I want right-click available to goes here</div>
<mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu"> 
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

CSS:

```
.context-menu-trigger { position: absolute }
```

TS:

```
...
@Component( ... )
export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) public menuTrigger : MatMenuTrigger;
    public menuLeft = 0;
    public menuTop = 0;
    ...
    openContextMenu(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.menuLeft = event.x;
        this.menuTop = event.y;
        this.menuTrigger.openMenu();
    }
}
```

We are currently on @angular 4.4 and @angular/material 2.0.0-beta.12.

Comment: works perfectly fine to me... actually thinking of making it so it pops where the user last right click would be harder ^^''' are you sure you're not having issues with device width/height changed by chrome dev tools or anything and it's just displaced?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me.  I'm using Chrome v61 to test.  I closed the devtools.  To verify.  I will click at the bottom right of the div, and the menu will show up at the top left.  On the next click, I will click at the top left, and the menu moves to the bottom right.  Etc.

Comment: I'm having a doubt but I can't test it right now... This is pure speculation but could it be that event coordinates are given from the realitive 0 of the component you're in? I tested this on a single component page and it worked.. so maybe you're nesting it inside another component and that's the problem.. I have never dealt with event coordinates in angular so I never tester I'm purely guessing.. but you could try it..

Comment: Your solution worked just out of the box for me, thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's not safe to rely on timeout.
Set direct style for your span trigger to get instant position update:

```html
<span style="position:fixed;" #spanTrigger class="context-menu-trigger" #matTrigger="matMenuTrigger" [matMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenu"></span>
<div (contextmenu)="openContextMenu($event, matTrigger, spanTrigger)"> stuff that I want right-click available to goes here</div>
<mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu"> 
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Handler:

```js
openContextMenu(
    event: MouseEvent,
    trigger: MatMenuTrigger,
    triggerElement: HTMLElement
) {
    triggerElement.style.left = event.clientX + 5 + "px";
    triggerElement.style.top = event.clientY + 5 + "px";
    if (trigger.menuOpen) {
        trigger.closeMenu();
        trigger.openMenu();
    } else {
        trigger.openMenu();
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: you should use renderer2 to set syle, but really good catch. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I came across this and found a fix by delaying the trigger.openMenu() to occur after the styling position takes place

Observable.timer(100).subscribe(t => { this.menuTrigger.openMenu() });

Answer (score 1):

I use the event.layerX and event.layerY for the menuLeft and menuTop

Answer (score -2):

I used this code to solve problem with menu position (works for me in Angular 8):

```
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.menuTrigger.openMenu();
    }, 200);
```